# Count not returning any values

Tags: sql

```
SELECT ISNULL(COUNT([Territory ID]), 0) AS Number_Terr
FROM [A2943_Short].[dbo].[Terr] 
INNER JOIN [A2943_Short].[dbo].[Terr_Sales] ON [A2943_Short].[dbo].[Terr_Sales].[ims_id] = [A2943_Short].[dbo].[Terr].[ims_id]
HAVING SUM([TRX_Qty]) = 0
```

I am having trouble getting the `COUNT` function to return a value of 0. It is just returning blanks

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do?  The most obvious thing is to remove the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT([Territory ID]) AS Number_Terr
FROM [A2943_Short].[dbo].[Terr] T JOIN
      [A2943_Short].[dbo].[Terr_Sales] TS
      ON TS.[ims_id] = T.[ims_id];
```

Of course, that might not be what you really want to do.

Note that this removes the `ISNULL()`.  `COUNT()` does not return `NULL` values; it returns `0`, so that is not needed.  The query also introduces table aliases so it is easier to write and read -- and to fix to get right if the logic isn't quite correct.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, you want two levels of subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT [Territory ID]
      FROM [A2943_Short].[dbo].[Terr] T JOIN
            [A2943_Short].[dbo].[Terr_Sales] TS
            ON TS.[ims_id] = T.[ims_id]
      GROUP BY [Territory ID]
      HAVING SUM([TRX_Qty]) = 0
     ) t;
```

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific. I am trying to count the number of Territories that have a total sum of TRX_Qty  equal to zero. I am trying to find the number of territories with  no cumulative sales